# iOS app is not responding on press action in different country/region?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, appstore-approval

We are facing some REALLY weird issue with our ios app in React Native. Testers from Apple in United States region are unable to press any button in app (screen with TouchableOpacity and Button component, Node version: 0.62.2.)
The weirdest thing is, that testing in our region (in particular Czech Republic) it works like a charm in every simulator combination of OS/device/country/language and also on our real devices with different operating system. (｢๑•₃•)｢ ʷʱʸ?

Has anybody facing similar issue with React Native and iOS?

We have already excluded these error causes:

- network (it works ok it's even sending data)
- app crash or exception - nothing logged
- wrong import: correct ToucahbleOpacity from react-native

What we see from logs, the difference is only the region, so we are leading this path, but in fact feeling hopeless little bit. ಥ_ಥ

Answer (score 1):

For those who will face similar very weird issues and drown in despair as we did. (ó﹏ò｡)

What helps at the end? We didn't find the exact issue, we couldn't simulate it on any device, but what we did was complete update of React Native, React, Xcode and all libraries and tools related to app. That was ultimate solution, but was necessary. (~_^)

Comment: That's so strange. So you updated the React Native version to 0.64 version?

Comment: Jop...we have updated everything: yarn version: 1.22.10, node version: v14.16.0, nvm version: v0.35.3, Xcode version: 12.5.1, React Native version: 0.64.2 and also OS to Big Sur :D

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a issue in the [react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues) repo, more people should know about this strange problem.

Comment: That would be nice, but in fact I don't know what would I write there ... this issue was so weird, that we didn't have any clue what it could be, what can be the cause and even how to reproduce it ... I think I wouldn't help with raising such issue